# NSURL comparison: compare with different URL

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, if-statement, nsurl

I have searched for this but i didn't get the correct keyword to get the result.
so i come with question.
Here is my question.

How to give if condition for checking, Whether the given NSURL path is for the FOLDER (or) a text file.
       For Example:

```
 if ([the given url is for FOlDERS])  
 {
    //i want to so something
 }
 else if([it contains .rtf files])
 {
    //i want to so something
 }
  else if([it contains .mov files])
  {
    //i want to so something
  }
```

my url's are

```
Users/Desktop/dr/dg.rtf  
Users/Desktop/dr/dhoom.mov  
Users/Desktop/dr/SampleTest/
```

give me some suggestions.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
BOOL isDir;
NSURL *yourURL;

NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
BOOL result = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[yourURL path] isDirectory:&isDir];
if (result) {
    // ok yourURL is pointing to something real
    if (isDir) {
        // yourURL is a directory
    }
    else if ([[yourURL pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"mov"])
    {
        // yourURL is a .mov
    }
    else if ([[yourURL pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"rtf"])
    {
        // yourURL is a .rtf
    }
}
[fileManager release];
```

combination of **Michal** and **werner** answers with fixed syntax.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSURL *url;
//set url here

if([url isFileURL])
{
  if([url pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"mov"])
  {
    //do .mov stuff
  }
  else if([url pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"rtf"]
  {
    //do .rtf stuff
  }
}
else
{
   if([[url lastPathComponent] isEqualToString:@"SampleTest"])
   {
     //do your SampleTest folder stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: not only for sampleTest there are so many folders. i need to check totally.. how to do.,.,

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/fileExistsAtPath%3aisDirectory%3a) for `NSFileManager`.

It contains a method that does exactly what you need :

```
- (BOOL)fileExistsAtPath:(NSString *)path isDirectory:(BOOL *)isDirectory
```

Comment: I don't think that's exactly what he needs at all.

Comment: yes. i dont want to check whether the file is exists or not,. i want to check whether given url is for folders (or) some kind of files.,.

Comment: ok, can you elaborate on how you get the URL because that would help to suggest a better approach